# How do I fix ".htaccess RewriteRule results in duplicated pages"

Tags: .htaccess, url, duplicates, seo

Good day.

We have a web portal coded in vanilla PHP that has a blog section where
`[mysite.com/blog.php?blog=1]` outputs the content of the desired file.

This led to our SEO expert pointing out that it is a poorly formatted URL for SEO.

We then decided to use .htaccess to display named URLs

`blog=Residential_Relocation   ->   blogs.php?blog=1` to output `[mysite.com/blog.php?blog=Residential_Relocation]`

But now it is seen as a duplicate.

How can we go about to only read the file from the blog=1 URL without it being picked up by crawlers?

```
php_value session.cookie_lifetime 18000
php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 18000

RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
  # Compress HTML, CSS, JavaScript, Text, XML and fonts
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/vnd.ms-fontobject
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-opentype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-otf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-truetype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-ttf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/opentype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/otf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/ttf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/x-icon
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml

  # Remove browser bugs (only needed for really old browsers)
  BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
  BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
  BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
  Header append Vary User-Agent
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
  ExpiresActive On

  # Images
  ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType image/webp "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType image/svg+xml "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"

  # Video
  ExpiresByType video/webm "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType video/mp4 "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType video/mpeg "access plus 1 year"

  # Fonts
  ExpiresByType font/ttf "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType font/otf "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType font/woff "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType font/woff2 "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType application/font-woff "access plus 1 year"

  # CSS, JavaScript
  ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 month"

  # Others
  ExpiresByType application/pdf "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType image/vnd.microsoft.icon "access plus 1 year"
</IfModule>

# BEGIN cPanel-generated php ini directives, do not edit
# Manual editing of this file may result in unexpected behavior.
# To make changes to this file, use the cPanel MultiPHP INI Editor (Home >> Software >> MultiPHP INI Editor)
# For more information, read our documentation (https://go.cpanel.net/EA4ModifyINI)
<IfModule php7_module>
   php_flag display_errors On
   php_value max_execution_time 300
   php_value max_input_time 600
   php_value max_input_vars 10000
   php_value memory_limit 320M
   php_value post_max_size 80M
   php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 14400
   php_value session.save_path "/var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php74"
   php_value upload_max_filesize 20M
   php_flag zlib.output_compression Off
</IfModule>
<IfModule lsapi_module>
   php_flag display_errors On
   php_value max_execution_time 300
   php_value max_input_time 600
   php_value max_input_vars 10000
   php_value memory_limit 320M
   php_value post_max_size 80M
   php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 14400
   php_value session.save_path "/var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php74"
   php_value upload_max_filesize 20M
   php_flag zlib.output_compression Off
</IfModule>
# END cPanel-generated php ini directives, do not edit

# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php74” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php74___lsphp .php .php7 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit

<Files 403.shtml>
order allow,deny
allow from all
</Files>

deny from 45.129.137.249
deny from 43.242.128.31
deny from 104.131.124.162
deny from 216.144.247.254

RewriteRule ^blog=Professional_Packing_and_Wrapping_Services/?$ blogs.php?blog=1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^blog=GIT,_All_Risk_and_General_Insurance/?$ blogs.php?blog=2 [NC]
RewriteRule ^blog=Relocation_Station/?$ blogs.php?blog=4 [NC]

RewriteRule ^category=Residential_Relocation/?$ blogs.php?cat=1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^category=Commercial_Relocation/?$ blogs.php?cat=2 [NC]
RewriteRule ^category=International_Relocation/?$ blogs.php?cat=3 [NC]
RewriteRule ^category=Pet_Transport/?$ blogs.php?cat=4 [NC]
RewriteRule ^category=Car_Transport/?$ blogs.php?cat=5 [NC]
RewriteRule ^category=Wrapping_Services/?$ blogs.php?cat=6 [NC]
RewriteRule ^category=Packing_Services/?$ blogs.php?cat=7 [NC]
RewriteRule ^category=Courier_Services/?$ blogs.php?cat=8 [NC]
RewriteRule ^category=Cleaning_Services/?$ blogs.php?cat=9 [NC]
RewriteRule ^category=Storage/?$ blogs.php?cat=10 [NC]
RewriteRule ^category=Insurance/?$ blogs.php?cat=11 [NC]
RewriteRule ^category=Moving_Tips/?$ blogs.php?cat=12 [NC]
RewriteRule ^category=General/?$ blogs.php?cat=13 [NC]

RewriteRule ^keyword=relocation/?$ blogs.php?key=1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^keyword=residential/?$ blogs.php?key=2 [NC]
RewriteRule ^keyword=commercial/?$ blogs.php?key=3 [NC]
RewriteRule ^keyword=international/?$ blogs.php?key=4 [NC]
RewriteRule ^keyword=storage/?$ blogs.php?key=5 [NC]
RewriteRule ^keyword=car/?$ blogs.php?key=6 [NC]
RewriteRule ^keyword=vehicle/?$ blogs.php?key=7 [NC]
RewriteRule ^keyword=pet/?$ blogs.php?key=8 [NC]
RewriteRule ^keyword=insurance/?$ blogs.php?key=9 [NC]
RewriteRule ^keyword=packers/?$ blogs.php?key=10 [NC]
RewriteRule ^keyword=packing/?$ blogs.php?key=11 [NC]
RewriteRule ^keyword=courier/?$ blogs.php?key=12 [NC]
RewriteRule ^keyword=wrapping/?$ blogs.php?key=13 [NC]
RewriteRule ^keyword=cleaning/?$ blogs.php?key=14 [NC]
RewriteRule ^keyword=long_distance/?$ blogs.php?key=15 [NC]
RewriteRule ^keyword=transport/?$ blogs.php?key=16 [NC]
RewriteRule ^keyword=moving/?$ blogs.php?key=17 [NC]
RewriteRule ^keyword=affordable/?$ blogs.php?key=18 [NC]
RewriteRule ^keyword=professional/?$ blogs.php?key=19 [NC]
RewriteRule ^keyword=cost_effective/?$ blogs.php?key=20 [NC]
RewriteRule ^keyword=tips/?$ blogs.php?key=21 [NC]
```

Comment: @anubhava - I added it to my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove duplicate penalty by SEO you may block all URLs pointing to internal URI i.e. `/blogs.php?blog=<number>`, `/blogs.php?cat=<number>` and `/blogs.php?key=<number>`.

Insert a new rule just below `RewriteEngine On` line:

```sh
RewriteEngine On

# prohibit direct access to internal URIs
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /blogs\.php\?(blog|cat|key)=\d+ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F]

# existing rules go below this line
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing nice answer sir, I have 1 doubt, could you please do let me know how its getting considered as duplicate entry on SEO? And how you found out that these urls needs to be forbidden? Will be grateful to you, Thank you sir.

Comment: It is recorded a dupe content because website is serving same page for 2 URLs: `/blog=Residential_Relocation`  and `/blogs.php?blog=1`. By blocking direct access to `/blogs.php?blog=1` that dupe marking will be removed (after few weeks)